# Fourier transform of $\dfrac{\cos(\beta x)}{a^{4} + x^{4}}$

Tags: fourier-transform, complex-integration, integral-transforms

What I've done so far:

$$\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{2\pi}}\left[\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\dfrac{e^{i(\beta + k)x}}{a^{4} + x^{4}}dx +\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\dfrac{e^{i(k - \beta)x}}{a^{4} + x^{4}}dx\right] = \\\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\dfrac{e^{i(\beta + k)x}}{(a^2 + ix^2)(a^{2} -ix^2)}dx +\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\dfrac{e^{i(k - \beta)x}}{(a^2 + ix^2)(a^{2} -ix^2)}dx]$$

considering that de Fourier transform is given by:

$$F(K) = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)e^{ikx}dx$$

My problem is that I can't find a way of plotting the poles of the function so I can find a integration contourn

Comment: Hint: if $a>0$ the poles with $\Im x>0$ are $ae^{i\pi/4},\,ae^{3i\pi/4}$, both first-order. Writing the cosine as the real part of a complex exponential, not the average of two CEs, saves you considering other poles.

Comment: You mean write the exponential as $Re(e^{i(\beta + k )x}) = cos((\beta + k)x )$?

Comment: Apart from you forgetting a factor of $x$ in the argument on the RHS, yes, exactly. The final answer is the real part of one contour integral around a semicircular contour.

Comment: Is $a$ a real number?

Comment: Yes!, I was able to decompose the polynomial into simple poles and solve the complex integral